# YouTube video shows "An error has occurred, please try again later" on one STB(QTWebkit 4.8)

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, qtwebkit, youtube-iframe-api

We have a YouTube app on one STB (QTWebkit 4.8), which is using YouTube `iframe` embedded player, all metadata fetched from YouTube Data API.

The app was running fine for several months, but right now when you are going to play some videos (almost 90%), it showed:

> "An error has occurred, please try again later" on the screen.

*But if you run the app URL on Chrome, everything works fine.*

We think it maybe because YouTube back-end blocked the `IP` or the request from this STB since the error message just like the blocking way from YouTube for the browser running an "ad block" extension. And one more thing we found related to this is that all "/ads" request got 403 forbidden from the STB, but 200 OK from Chrome.

Is there anyone came across this before? Any input will be helpful.